# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_fields'

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp

Estoy realizando un reporte por **QWEB** en **Odoo 12**, solo debe tomar los campos de un modelo llamado **fico.respuesta**, el reporte se imprime sin ningún problema, sin embargo, al llamar a los campos del modelo genera el error antes mencionado:

```
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_fields'
Template: f360_circulo_credito.report_cdc_document
Path: /templates/t/t/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span
Node: <span t-field="doc.nombre"/>
```

A continuación anexo el código del modelo:

```
class FICORespuesta(models.Model):
    _name = 'fico.respuesta'
    _description = 'CdC Fico Respuesta'

    #CAMPO ID
    partner_id = fields.Char('Partner id')

    #DATOS ID
    folio = fields.Char(string='Folio')
    nombre = fields.Char(string='Nombre')
    rfc = fields.Char(string='RFC')
```

El código del reporte no es más que una plantilla xml que se llama **f360_report_fico_template.xml**, hasta ahora no he llamado más campos más que el campo **nombre**

Anexo el código de la plantilla.

Pido disculpas por la mala identación, en Visual Studio no se ve de esta forma.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="report_cdc_document">
    <t t-call="web.external_layout">
        <t t-set="doc"  />
      <!-- t-value="doc.with_context(lang=doc.partner_id.lang)" -->
<style>
table {
  width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family:verdana;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #fff;
}
#t01 th {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
</style>

        <div class="page">
            <div class="oe_structure"/>
            <h2  class="text-center" style="font-size:24px;font-family:verdana;" color="teal">
                      <table class="table">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                            <td><h2 style="font-size:24px" color="teal">Reporte de Crédito: FICO Score</h2></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
            </h2>


            <div class="col-auto mw-100 mb-2" style="font-size:20px; color:grey; font-family:verdana;">
                    <strong>Datos Generales</strong>
            </div>
                  <div>
                    <table id="t01">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <t t-set="colspan"  t-value="3"/>
                                    <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="width:350px">Nombre</th>
                                    <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="width:350px">RFC</th>
                                    <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="width:350px">Folio</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="fico_tbody" >
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><span t-field= "doc.nombre"/></td>
                                      <td></td>
                                      <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
            <div class="col-auto mw-100 mb-2" style="font-size:20px; color:grey; font-family:verdana;">
                    <strong>Datos del reporte:</strong>
            </div>
                    <div>
                    <table id="t01">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <t t-set="colspan"  t-value="4"/>
                                  <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="width:350px">Apellido Paterno</th>
                                  <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="width:350px">Apellido Materno</th>
                                  <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="width:350px">Nombre</th>
                                  <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="width:350px">Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="fico_tbody" >
                                     <tr>
                                      <td></td>
                                      <td></td>
                                      <td></td>
                                      <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>


            <div class="oe_structure"/>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="report_cdc_fico">
  <t t-call="web.html_container">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
      <t t-call="f360_circulo_credito.report_cdc_document" />
      <!-- t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang" -->
    </t>
  </t>
</template>

</odoo>
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN
Agrego también el código del controlador que manda a llamar el reporte y su respectiva plantilla en XML.

También comento que la variable **doc** vendría siendo el nombre del modelo, por lo que en este caso sería lo mismo `fico_respuesta.nombre`

```
@api.multi
def print_fico_report(self):
    for record in self:

        nombre = self.nombre
        rfc = self.rfc
        lang = self.env.context.get('lang')

        partner_id = self.partner_id

        return self.env.ref('f360_circulo_credito.action_report_cdc_fico')\
            .with_context(discard_logo_check=True).report_action(self)
```

Comento que en este XML llamado **f360_report.xml** vendrán declarados de la misma forma más reportes en un futuro.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report
            id="action_report_cdc_fico"
            string="Reporte de Crédito: FICO Score"
            model="fico.respuesta"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            file="f360_circulo_credito.report_cdc_fico"
            name="f360_circulo_credito.report_cdc_fico"
            print_report_name="Reporte CdC: Fico Score"
        />
      
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Puede mostrar el código del Controller? Quiero ver cómo se pasa la `FICORespuesta` a la plantilla, si hablo correctamente.

Comment: De donde viene `doc`? Esto es lo que no puedo entender, pero pienso que es la razon que hay un error.

Comment: **doc** vendría siendo el nombre del modelo, sin embargo, en otros reportes toma **doc** por defecto, solo fue necesario definirlo en la plantilla xml de `f360_report_fico_template.xml`

Comment: Lo siento. Yo pienso que entiendo que es la problema, pero no conozco QWeb y por eso no se la manera de arreglarla. Me parece raro que `doc` esta disponible por defecto en algunas plantillas pero no en esta. Tal vez `docs` esta disponible? Miro [esta pagina de la documentacion](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/reports.html#report).

Comment: probablemente se deba a un fallo en cuando al id de la plantilla o entre la plantilla y el usuario, pero tendré que revisar

Comment: Creo que hay dos opciones - 1) necesita quitar la linea `<t t-set="doc"  />` porque esta anulando el `doc` disponible por defecto, o 2) necesita anadir un `t-value` que referiere al doc del modelo. Pero no entiendo donde el modelo `doc` se pasa a la plantanilla. Tal vez necesita pasarlo en el controller tambien para hacer que esta disponible. No se. Pero el mensaje `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_fields'` me hace pensar que esa linea es la problema. `doc` no debe ser un `str` y creo que probablemente esa linea sin `t-value` resulta en asignar el string vacio a `doc`.